# ElasticSearch with pyes: bulk index

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I have a 200M documents index I would like to reindex.

I wrote the following script that goes over documents in the old index and puts them with balk insert into the new index.

The size of each bulk is 2000 documents.

```
 search_obj = pyes.query.Search(query = pyes.query.MatchAllQuery(), start=resume_from)

 old_index_iterator = self.esconn.search(search_obj, self.index_name)
 counter = 0
 BULK_SIZE = 2000

 for doc in old_index_iterator:
   self.esconn.index(doc=doc, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, index=new_index_name, id=doc.get_id(), bulk=True)
   counter += 1

   if counter % BULK_SIZE == 0:
     self.logger.debug("Refreshing...")
     self.esconn.refresh()
     self.logger.debug("Refresh done.")


 self.esconn.refresh()
```

**Observation:**

1. The speed that I get is very slow: around 150 documents / minute.
2. The time of the refresh operation is 0. If I remove the index command (just read from the DB) - I speed up 10 times.

**Conclusion:**

- The index ignores the bulk=True flag, and pushes every single document to the ES server.

Anyone know please help me to figure out why bulk=True has no effect?

Comment: Check this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002982/elasticsearch-bulk-index-in-chunks-using-pyes  for help .

Answer (score 0):

Your low speed is about reading from the old index not inserting into the new one.

Try scan mode and scroll when read:

```
result_set = self.esconn.search(pyes.query.MatchAllQuery(),indices=INDEX_NAME, doc_types=INDEX_TYPE, scan=True, scroll_timeout="10m")
for doc in result_set:
    pass # do your insert task
```

And also the default refresh size is 400 and interval is 1s, usually it does not need to reset this setting.