# How to use Bulk API to store the keywords in ES by using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have to store some message in ElasticSearch integrate with my python program. 
Now what I try to store the message is:

```
d={"message":"this is message"}
    for index_nr in range(1,5):
        ElasticSearchAPI.addToIndex(index_nr, d)
        print d
```

That means if I have 10 messages then I have to repeat my code 10 times. 
So what I want to do is try to make a script file or batch file.
I've checked the [ElasticSearch Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), BULK API is possible to use. 
The format should be something like below:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "index1"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

what I did is:

```
{"index":{"_index":"test1","_type":"message","_id":"1"}}
{"message":"it is red"}
{"index":{"_index":"test2","_type":"message","_id":"2"}}
{"message":"it is green"}
```

I also use curl tool to store the doc.

```
$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @message.json
```

Now I want to use **my Python code** to store the file to the Elastic Search.

Comment: Have a look at some python clients like pyes : https://github.com/aparo/pyes OR the elasticsearch official client https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py

Comment: Thank you so much, I check some client and I try to use pyelasticsearch. And I already store the stall with bulk index with pyelastic. In pyelasticsearch the doc file will be inside the code. Is that possible to put the doc file which I want to bulk index outside the program?

Answer (score 150):

```
from datetime import datetime

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers

es = Elasticsearch()

actions = [
  {
    "_index": "tickets-index",
    "_type": "tickets",
    "_id": j,
    "_source": {
        "any":"data" + str(j),
        "timestamp": datetime.now()}
  }
  for j in range(0, 10)
]

helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

Comment: I didn't leave any comment because I guess the codes are quite clear.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.  A side note if you don't provide "_id" one will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: I'm using bulk() as described in this answer, but as I check my index while my script is running, I don't see anything being uploaded to the index. When I used the index() function to upload one-at-a-time, I immediately see results. Not sure what's happening. I'm also not getting any errors nor exceptions. Help please!

Comment: @Soubriquet: facing same issue. Any luck?

Comment: Same issue has anyone figured this out?

Comment: See my answer below that uses Python Generators, allowing you to add millions of data to ES without having the need for more RAM.

Comment: I changed the type from `_type` to `doc_type` - and it works for me

Answer (score 51):

Although @justinachen 's code helped me start with py-elasticsearch, after looking in the source code let me do a simple improvement:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
j = 0
actions = []
while (j <= 10):
    action = {
        "_index": "tickets-index",
        "_type": "tickets",
        "_id": j,
        "_source": {
            "any":"data" + str(j),
            "timestamp": datetime.now()
            }
        }
    actions.append(action)
    j += 1

helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

`helpers.bulk()` already does the segmentation for you. And by segmentation I mean the chucks sent every time to the server. If you want to reduce the chunk of sent documents do: `helpers.bulk(es, actions, chunk_size=100)`

Some handy info to get started:

`helpers.bulk()` is just a wrapper of the `helpers.streaming_bulk` but the first accepts a list which makes it handy.

`helpers.streaming_bulk` has been based on `Elasticsearch.bulk()` so you do not need to worry about what to choose.

So in most cases, [helpers.bulk()](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) should be all you need.

Comment: in python, I would strongly suggest the use of list/dictionary comprehensions (in combination with enumerate for the variable j and range-indexing to ensure j <= 10)  instead of loops. This is a more readable style of coding, and allows to create generators (python3), preventing premature materialization.

Comment: If you cannot load all your documents into a memory to let helpers.bulk do batching for you than this won't work and still requires you to batch your calls to helpers.bulk.

Answer (score 43):

(the other approaches mentioned in this thread use python list for the ES update, which is not a good solution today, especially when you need to add millions of data to ES)

**Better approach** is using **python generators** -- *process gigs of data without going out of memory or compromising much on speed*.

Below is an example snippet from a practical use case - adding data from nginx log file to ES for analysis.

```
def decode_nginx_log(_nginx_fd):
    for each_line in _nginx_fd:
        # Filter out the below from each log line
        remote_addr = ...
        timestamp   = ...
        ...

        # Index for elasticsearch. Typically timestamp.
        idx = ...

        es_fields_keys = ('remote_addr', 'timestamp', 'url', 'status')
        es_fields_vals = (remote_addr, timestamp, url, status)

        # We return a dict holding values from each line
        es_nginx_d = dict(zip(es_fields_keys, es_fields_vals))

        # Return the row on each iteration
        yield idx, es_nginx_d   # <- Note the usage of 'yield'

def es_add_bulk(nginx_file):
    # The nginx file can be gzip or just text. Open it appropriately.
    ...

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

    # NOTE the (...) round brackets. This is for a generator.
    k = ({
            "_index": "nginx",
            "_type" : "logs",
            "_id"   : idx,
            "_source": es_nginx_d,
         } for idx, es_nginx_d in decode_nginx_log(_nginx_fd))

    helpers.bulk(es, k)

# Now, just run it.
es_add_bulk('./nginx.1.log.gz')
```

This skeleton demonstrates the usage of generators. You can use this even on a bare machine if you need to. And you can go on expanding on this to tailor to your needs quickly.

Python Elasticsearch reference [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html).

Answer (score 12):

There are two options which I can think of at the moment:

**1. Define index name and document type with each entity:**

```
es_client = Elasticsearch()

body = []
for entry in entries:
    body.append({'index': {'_index': index, '_type': 'doc', '_id': entry['id']}})
    body.append(entry)

response = es_client.bulk(body=body)
```

**2. Provide the default index and document type with the method:**

```
es_client = Elasticsearch()

body = []
for entry in entries:
    body.append({'index': {'_id': entry['id']}})
    body.append(entry)

response = es_client.bulk(index='my_index', doc_type='doc', body=body)
```

**Works with:**

ES version:6.4.0

ES python lib: 6.3.1

Answer (score 2):

My working code

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections
import pandas as pd


# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10, 'NY'], ['nick', 15, 'NY'], ['juli', 14, 'NY'], ['akshay', 30, 'IND'], ['Amit', 14, 'IND']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Country'])

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers

es_client = connections.create_connection(hosts=['http://localhost:9200/'])
def doc_generator(df):
    df_iter = df.iterrows()
    for index, document in df_iter:
        yield {
                "_index": 'age_sample',
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_source": document,
            }

helpers.bulk(es_client, doc_generator(df))

#get data from elastic search
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
s = Search(index="age_sample").query("match", Name='nick')
```