# elasticsearch python bulk api (elasticsearch-py)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I'm confused about py-elasticsearch bulk 
@Diolor solution works
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118497/4101879), but I would like to use plain es.bulk()

My code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
doc = '''\n {"host":"logsqa","path":"/logs","message":"test test","@timestamp":"2014-10-02T10:11:25.980256","tags":["multiline","mydate_0.005"]} \n'''
result = es.bulk(index="logstash-test", doc_type="test", body=doc)
```

The ERROR is:

```
 No handlers could be found for logger "elasticsearch"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./log-parser-perf.py", line 55, in <module>
    insertToES()
  File "./log-parser-perf.py", line 46, in insertToES
    res = es.bulk(index="logstash-test", doc_type="test", body=doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 70, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 570, in bulk
    params=params, body=self._bulk_body(body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 274, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 57, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 83, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, u'ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]')
```

Generated url for POST call is

> /logstash-test/test/_bulk

and the POST body is:

> {"host":"logsqa","path":"/logs","message":"test
>   test","@timestamp":"2014-10-02T10:11:25.980256","tags":["multiline","mydate_0.005"]}

So I did che curl by hand:
This curl does not work:

```
> curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/logstash-test/test2/_bulk -d
> '{"host":"logsqa","path":"/logs","message":"test
> test","@timestamp":"2014-10-02T10:11:25.980256","tags":["multiline","mydate_0.005"]}
> '
>
> {"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]","status":500}
```

So the error is partially OK, but I did expect that elasticsearch.bulk() will manage properly the input args.

The pythonf function is:

```
bulk(*args, **kwargs)
    :arg body: The operation definition and data (action-data pairs), as
        either a newline separated string, or a sequence of dicts to
        serialize (one per row).
    :arg index: Default index for items which don't provide one
    :arg doc_type: Default document type for items which don't provide one
        :arg consistency: Explicit write consistency setting for the operation
    :arg refresh: Refresh the index after performing the operation
    :arg routing: Specific routing value
    :arg replication: Explicitly set the replication type (default: sync)
    :arg timeout: Explicit operation timeout
```

Comment: I would advise you to use `helpers.bulk()` unless you want to do something more complex of course. You can read the source code of how helpers.bulk is made [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py) and implement your own if you wish. helpers.bulk wraps helpers.streaming_bulk which finally wraps the es.bulk.

Answer (score 7):

In case someone is currently trying to use the bulk api and wondering what the format should be, here's what worked for me:

```
doc = [
    {
        'index':{
            '_index': index_name,
            '_id' : <some_id>,
            '_type':<doc_type>
        }
    },
    {
        'field_1': <value>,
        'field_2': <value>
    }
]

docs_as_string = json.dumps(doc[0]) + '\n' + json.dumps(doc[1]) + '\n'
client.bulk(body=docs_as_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

From @HonzaKral  on github

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/issues/135

Hi sirkubax,

the bulk api (as do all the others) follows very closely the bulk api format for elasticsearch itself, so the body would have to be:

doc = '''{"index": {}}\n{"host":"logsqa","path":"/logs","message":"test test","@timestamp":"2014-10-02T10:11:25.980256","tags":["multiline","mydate_0.005"]}\n'''
for it to work. Alternatively it could be a list of those two dicts.

This is a complicated and clumsy format to work with from python, that's why I tried to create a more convenient way to work with bulk in elasticsearch.helpers.bulk (0). It simply accepts an iterator of documents, will extract any optional metadata from it (like _id, _type etc) and construct (and execute) the bulk request for you. For more info on the accepted formats see the docs for streaming_bulk above which is a helper to process the stream in iterative manner (one at a time from the point of the user, batched in chunks in the background).

Hope this helps.

0 - http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk

Comment: Could you perhaps add a working example? It is still a bit unclear to me what the exact syntax of a bulk query would be.