# Bulk-API with ElasticSearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I wish to use the Bulk-API option with ElasticSearch-py. I try to use the bulk-api with this example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
doc ={.....}
result = es.bulk(index="my_index", doc_type="my_doc_type", body=doc)
```

My index and my doc type is good but, I've got this error:

> WARNING:elasticsearch:POST /my_index/my_doc_type/_bulk [status:500
>   request:0.002s]

Why i've got this error ?
Thanks in advance.

***Update***

after some debugging, I manage to display this error:

> {"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no
>   requests added;]","status":500}

Comment: HTTP status 500 is Internal Server Error, are there any errors in the Elasticsearch logs?

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python/23118497#23118497
I'll try this option.

Comment: I added this answer that uses python generators here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39069077/235415 You should be able to process GBs of data with this.