# How to insert an already created json-format string to Elasticsearch Bulk

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api, elasticsearch-bulk

In a python script,

I'm trying for **elasticsearch.helpers.bulk** to store multiple records.

I will get a json-format string from another software, and I want to attach it in the source part

I got the helpers.bulk format by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python)

part of my code:

```
def saveES(output,name):
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}]) 
    output = output.split('\n')
    i=0
    datas=[]
    while i<len(output):
            data = {
                    "_index":"name",
                    "_type":"typed",
                    "_id":saveES.counter,
                    "_source":[[PROBLEM]]
            }
            i+=1
            saveES.counter+=1
            datas.append(data)

    helpers.bulk(es, datas)
```

I would like to attach a json-format string in [[PROBLEM]]

How can I attach it in? I have tried hard, but it is not output in the correct..

if I use:

```
"_source":{
"image_name":'"'+name+'",'+output[i]
}
```

and print data result is:

```
{'_type': 'typed', '_id': 0, '_source': {'image_name': '"nginx","features": "os,disk,package", "emit_shortname": "f0b03efe94ec", "timestamp": "2017-08-18T17:25:46+0900", "docker_image_tag": "latest"'}, '_index': 'name'}
```

This result show that combined into a single string.

but I expect:

```
{'_type': 'typed', '_id': 0, '_source': {'image_name': 'nginx','features': 'os,disk,package', 'emit_shortname': 'f0b03efe94ec', 'timestamp': '2017-08-18T17:25:46+0900', 'docker_image_tag': 'latest'}, '_index': 'name'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many problems in your code.

1. You override the value of `data` in your loop
2. You don't respect any norms (Pesp8 and stuff)
3. You are while instead of a comprehension list
4. You created 2 useless variable
5. You instantiate your es in your function

Here is your improved code

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}]) # You don't have to initialise this variable every time you are calling the function but only once.


def save_es(output,es):  # Peps8 convention
    output = output.split('\n') # you don't need a while loop. A comprehension loop will avoid a lot of trouble
    data = [    # Please without s in data
       {
          "_index": "name",
          "_type": "typed",
          "_id": index,
          "_source": {
              "image_name":"name" + name}
        }
        for index, name in enumerate(output)
    ]    
    helpers.bulk(es, data)

save_es(output, es)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thank you, but I already try that. if I use **"image_name":"name"+output[i]** code, then data is **{'_type': 'typed', '_id': 3, '_source': {'image_name': '"nginx","feat": "foo", "os": 'foo''}, '_index': 'name'}**. However, correct data is **{'_type': 'typed', '_id': 3, '_source': {'image_name': 'nginx', 'feat': 'foo', 'os': 'foo'}, '_index': 'name'}**

Comment: Well your 'correct' result is not even a JSON document there is a coma problem. Moreover I should see something like 'image_name':'name' in your JSON following your code and my code, but none have it.

Comment: sorry. Actual results are very long, so I made a simple correction and it seems that a typo occurred.  In simple terms, **"image_name": "name1" + name2** In this case, name1 and name2 are combined into a single string. Is the 'name' value in your code a String?

Comment: The `name`value is what is present in your output so I guess a string

Comment: Yes, `name` is string .. oh .. I think my English skills are not enough, so communication seems to be hard... **two string are merged into a single string**, that is, all the data is stored in image_name as a string. I don't know if I delivered it correctly..... Do you use TeamViewer? I want to show the execution result screen in presentation mode.

Comment: Well I'm not on a computer now. Just try to give an example (simplify) of your input and what you expect as a result in data (to be indexed by ES) I will provide you with a working script to process your output.