# How can I get in python response for helpers.bulk function (elasticsearch API)?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I found great example on [helpers.bulk function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python) but I cannot find a response code. Everything I get from

```
helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

is

```
(1, [])
```

Comment: Can You show us your complete method?

Comment: It is the same as presented in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python). I expected, that `helpers.bulk(es, actions)` returns something like `Response [200]` or `{"acknowledged":true}`

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, were you able to get the response?

Comment: What if we want to get the same response as when the bulk API is called from command line?

Answer (score 2):

As written in [documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk):

> It returns a tuple with summary information - number of successfully executed actions and either list of errors or number of errors if stats_only is set to True
>   [...] If you need to process a lot of data and want to ignore/collect errors please consider using the streaming_bulk() helper which will just return the errors and not store them in memory.

with streaming_bulk() you have to use `raise_on_error` parameter for raise on error.
if you want to collect a lot of data i suggest to use [parallel_bulk()](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/helpers-parallel-bulk-in-python-not-working/39498/2) that is faster and more intuitive

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same way on AWS Lambda to push data to ElasticSearch:

```
print("Pushing data to ES <:", ESindex, ESmapping, ">", helpers.bulk(g.esClient, dataGenerator()))
```

Here the response

```
(1, [])
```

means 1 record pushed successfully to Elasticsearch. In case of a failure I got an **error log** like below and the Lambda Function Failed. (*I had removed the `[]` array brackets from the Json Data.*)

```
RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: index is missing;2: type is missing;3: index is missing;4: type is missing;5: index is missing;6: type is missing;7: index is missing;8: type is missing;9: index is missing;10: type is missing;11: index is missing;12: type is missing;13: index is missing;14: type is missing;15: index is missing;16: type is missing;17: index is missing;18: type is missing;19: index is missing;20: type is missing;21: index is missing;22: type is missing;23: index is missing;24: type is missing;25: index is missing;26: type is missing;27: index is missing;28: type is missing;29: index is missing;30: type is missing;'): RequestError
```