# How to persist a document in json format using elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am trying to update an existing elasticsearch data pipeline and would like to use elasticsearch-dsl more fully. In the current process we create a document as a json object and then use requests to PUT the object to the relevant elasticsearch index.

I would now like to use the elasticsearch-dsl save method but am left struggling to understand how I might do that when my object or document is constructed as json.

Current Process:

```
//import_script.py

index = 'objects'
doc = {"title": "A title", "Description": "Description", "uniqueID": "1234"}
doc_id = doc["uniqueID"]
elastic_url = 'http://elastic:changeme@localhost:9200/' + index + '/_doc/ + doc_id

api = ObjectsHandler()
api.put(elastic_url, doc)


//objects_handler.py

class ObjectsHandler():
     def put(self, url, object):
        result = requests.put(url, json=object)
        if result.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            print(result.text)
            result.raise_for_status()
```

Rather than using this PUT method, I would like to tap into the Document.save functionality available in the DSL but I can't translate the examples in the api documentation for my use case.

I have amended my ObjectsHandler so that it can create the objects index:

```
//objects_handler.py

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}],
                   http_auth='elastic:changeme')

connections.create_connection(es)

class Object(Document):
    physicalDescription = Text()
    title = Text()
    uniqueID = Text()

    class Index:
        name = 'objects'
        using = es

class ObjectsHandler():

   def init_mapping(self, index):
        Object.init(using=es, index=index)
```

This successfully creates an index when I call `api.init_mapping(index)` from the importer script.

The [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/elasticsearch-dsl/downloads/pdf/latest/) has this as an example for persisting the individual documents, where Article is the equivalent to my Object class:

```
# create and save and article
article = Article(meta={'id': 42}, title='Hello world!', tags=['test'])
article.body = ''' looong text '''
article.published_from = datetime.now()
article.save()
```

Is it possible for me to use this methodology but to persist my pre-constructed json object doc, rather than specifying individual attributes? I also need to be able to specify that the document id is the doc uniqueID.

I've extended my ObjectsHandler to include a save_doc method:

```
def save_doc(self, document, doc_id, index):
        new_obj = Object(meta={'id': doc_id}, 
                  title="hello", uniqueID=doc_id,
                  physicalDescription="blah")
        new_obj.save()
```

which does successfully save the object with uniqueID as id but I am unable to utilise the json object passed in to the method as `document`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success at this by using elasticsearch.py bulk helpers rather than elasticsearch-dsl.
The following resources were super helpful:

- [Blog - Bulk insert from json objects](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-bulk-index-elasticsearch-documents-from-a-json-file-using-python-753)
- [SO Answer, showing different ways to add keywords in a bulk action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614667/3258059)
- [Elastic documentation on bulk imports](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

In my question I was referring to a:

`doc = {"title": "A title", "Description": "Description", "uniqueID": "1234"}`

I actually have an array or list of 1 or more docs eg:

`documents = [{"title": "A title", "Description": "Description", "uniqueID": "1234"}, {"title": "Another title", "Description": "Another description", "uniqueID": "1235"}]`

I build up a body for the bulk import and append the id:

```
for document in documents:
   bulk_body.append({'index': {'_id': document["uniqueID"]}})
   bulk_body.append(document)
```

then run my new call to the helpers.bulk method:

`api_handler.save_docs(bulk_body, 'objects')`

with my objects_handler.py file looking like:

```
//objects_handler.py
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}],
                   http_auth='elastic:changeme')

connections.create_connection(es)

class Object(Document):
    physicalDescription = Text()
    title = Text()
    uniqueID = Text()

    class Index:
        name = 'objects'
        using = es

class ObjectsHandler():

   def init_mapping(self, index):
        Object.init(using=es, index=index)

   def save_docs(self, docs, index):
        print("Attempting to index the list of docs using helpers.bulk()")
        resp = es.bulk(index='objects', body=docs)
        print("helpers.bulk() RESPONSE:", resp)
        print("helpers.bulk() RESPONSE:", json.dumps(resp, indent=4))
```

This works for single docs in a json format or multiple docs.