# How to efficiently index a json file using elastic search and python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I'm trying to index a json file which contains 100,000+ objects. The format of my json file is:

```
    [{"ingredients": [{"text": "Butter"}, {"text": "Strawberries"}, {"text": "Granola"}], 
    "url": "http://tastykitchen.com/recipes/breakfastbrunch/yogurt-parfaits/", 
    "title": "Yogurt Parfaits", 
    "id": "000095fc1d", 
    "instructions": [{"text": "Layer all ingredients in a serving dish."}]},
     {"ingredients":
     .....]
```

This is in the form of a list. 
The python code I'm using write now to index the file is:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost','port': 9200}])
f = open('data.json')
import json
data = json.load(f)
for i in data:
     res = es.index(index='food',doc_type='Recipe',id=i["id"],body=i)
```

This method is taking a lot of time and is inefficient. The other methods I read needed the file in the format:

```
{"index": {"_index": "index_name", "_type": "index_type", "_id": "doc_id"}}
{"ingredients:....
```

Can you suggest an efficient method to index the file?

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Bulk API to store the keywords in ES by using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288770/how-to-use-bulk-api-to-store-the-keywords-in-es-by-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use Elasticsearch bulk Api**

> Performs multiple indexing or delete operations in a single API call. This reduces overhead and can greatly increase indexing speed.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html